# Show drop shadow on tooltips in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to show a drop shadow behind a Chart.js tooltip? I think there used to be a `showShadow:true` option, but it doesn't exist or isn't documented in the current version of Chart.js.

Comment: I think [someone is working on it](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/3221) but it is not yet available in the last version (2.2.1).

Comment: @Tektiv encouraging to see that, thanks!